# Enter numeric upto 2 place decimal at the max using regex replace "g"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

**Using Regex**, I want to allow the users to enter a maximum 5 digits no. and maximum of 2 decimal places allowing non-zero"

**like** 67823.67 or 1 or 1.2

**not like** .3 or 3242.34234.34 or 234.2342

Below code allows numeric and period. but also allows (.3 or 3242.34234.34 or 234.2342)

```
  $('input').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.match(/[^0-9\.]/g))
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    });
```

below code works as expected (source: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/javascript-validate-input-text-field.html)

```
 function testInputData(myfield, restrictionType) {
       var decimalOnly = /^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/ ;
       var myData = document.getElementById(myfield).value;
       if (myData !== '') {
           if (restrictionType.test(myData)) {
               alert('It is GOOD!');
           } else {
               alert('Your data input is invalid!');
           }
       } else {
           alert('Please enter data!');
       }
       return;
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
         Check for upto 2 Decimal:
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" id="input2" maxlength="30" size="30" />
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="Javascript:testInputData('input2',decimalOnly)" />
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

But, this is not working,

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.match(/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/g))
            this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/g, '');
    });
```

HTML

```
 <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Width="50"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}|\d{4}\.\d|\d{1,5})
```

It first checks to see if it fits the format `123.4` or `123.45`, failing that it checks to see if it fits the format `1234.5`, failing that it checks for any whole number between one and five digits.

You may wish to change the `{1,2}` to one if you don't want to permit `123.4` and instead want `123.40`.

If the entire field is to follow this format, you can do:

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if (!(this.value.match(/^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}|\d{4}\.\d|\d{1,5})$/)))
        alert('value DOES NOT fit pattern');
});
```

Update, I like this version of the above regex better, seems to work faster.

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var rmatch = new RegExp("^(?!(?=\\d+\\.\\d+$)(.{3,6}$)|(?=\\d{1,5}$)).+$");
    if (this.value.match(rmatch)) {
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

Per your comment and your use of global, you seem to maybe want something like this.. You cannot use a key event because it would trip when a person wanted to enter the decimal. You could modify this regex to accept that `onKeyDown`, but you'd need a seperate regex to catch. It ends up being a large mess, it's better to use `blur()` imo.

```
$('input').blur(function () {
    var rmatch = new RegExp("(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{4}\\.\\d|\\d{1,5})","g");
    var getMatches = this.value.match(rmatch);
    if (getMatches) {
        this.value = getMatches.join(" ");
    } else {
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

I wrote it that way based on your use of `g`, but perhaps you only want one number in the box (which is more likely). I would do this

```
$('input').blur(function () {
    var rmatch = new RegExp("^(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{4}\\.\\d|\\d{1,5})$","g");
    var getMatches = this.value.match(rmatch);
    if (!getMatches) {
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle demonstration of both methods.](http://jsfiddle.net/0btex74n/)**

Comment: That might work. But, I am expecting this to work as in the below logic, I don't know what I am missing, it allows me to enter anything other than numbers and period. (it's working reversely)

$('input').keyup(function () { var regex = /^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}|\d{4}\.\d|\d{1,5})$/g ;
             if (this.value.match(regex))
                this.value = this.value.replace(regex, ''); });